# 73 Gigatonnes of TNT upon collision could cause how many casualties?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, space, hard-science, space-colonization

So, after going through a some rough calculations, I figured my earlier question ran into a few problems regarding the final velocity of the asteroid. I pulled the mathematics a bit incorrect, so I dumbed it down to a speed of 40,264.06 m/s at final velocity. The Delta v, though is 26,264.06 m/s, and the initial speed was 14,000 m/s, and I still preserve the same angle and initial population numbers. The question I mentioned earlier is free to be erased now. Oh, and the number of 13 billion humans is from a guesstimate of population growth from 2100 to 2476 using a balanced 0.04% growth rate and starting from a recent UN estimate regarding the initial quantity of 11.2 billion people. So, given that this is 1999 FN53, which is a 900 metre in diameter asteroid, and it has 360 billion kg of mass (obtained from Russia's equivalent of NASA's Small Body Database), and those are factored in. Now.....it crashes 2 km off the coast of Guam, but the question is **how much of the globe's population (if that number is large enough) would perish?**

Comment: You still need to work on your math. I get something like 73 Gt at 40 km/sec.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Link?

Comment: No. Did the math based on your numbers..

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Oh. Fixed it!

Comment: I hope you didn't just take my word on it.

Comment: I think this question would be more suitable for xkcd: What If...? :D Your question takes this scenario - https://what-if.xkcd.com/12/ - and ramps it up to eleven. :D Do note however that you are still three magnitudes below the Chicxulub bolide. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicxulub_crater and closer to the eruption that created the La Gartia Caldera. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Garita_Caldera In brief: hard to say really. It will be one heck of a splash, but the question is if it will displace any significant amounts of water before slamming into the sea floor.

Comment: **Is this question intended to replace** [Is 3.04 teratonnes of TNT from an asteroid collision extinction level damage?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/39970/29) that was migrated here from [space.se]?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Actually, yes and you can copy-paste the scenario of the world situation from there, AND my question on the implications on extraplanetary policy if a colonial uprising partially succeeded. Feel free to conduct the necessary edits. :)

Comment: It's really confusing when details of a question are in another question, especially without linking to it, and some details are different and some are the same. It would be much easier to restate the whole question with all details.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent [impact calculator](http://www.purdue.edu/impactearth) for these sorts of questions.

Estimating the depth of the water 2 km off Guam from [this map](http://oceanexplorer.noaa.gov/explorations/06fire/background/plan/media/srof06_dive_sites.html) to be about 1500 m, and plugging in what I think your numbers are...

- 900 m asteroid
- 3000 kg/m^3 (dense rock)
- 57 degrees
- 40 km/s
- Impacting in 1500 m of water
- 2500 km to the [nearest major population centers](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/distances.html?n=91)

The results are:

- 219 Gigatons of TNT.
- No global damage.
- 13km crater in the sea floor.

Guam is no more, completely destroyed by the impact crater.  Fortunately for the rest of the planet, [Guam is a very, very isolated island](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Guam/@13.4432039,144.7270314,4z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x671f76ff930f24ef:0x5571ae91c5b3e5a6!6m1!1e1). It's a good choice for a "warning shot". The closest major population centers barely feel the initial impact and only receive a fine dusting of ejecta. 2 hours later the shockwave reaches them; they hear a loud bang and feel a light wind.

6 hours later the tsumani hits with an amplitude between 7 and 14 meters.  This is roughly the scale of [the tsunami which hit Japan in 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_T%C5%8Dhoku_earthquake_and_tsunami) and far smaller than the 2004 Indian Ocean tsunami.  Japan, New Guinea, and the Philippines will be hard hit.  Casualties will be in the tens of thousands, but improved tsumani defenses in 400 years might shrug this off.

Either way, it's nothing which hasn't been seen before. But the now steaming surface of the Pacific Ocean where Guam used to be might give the inhabitants of Earth pause.

Since it impacted in deep water, there won't be a lot of dust kicked into the atmosphere, but there will be a lot of water vapor. According to [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012821X10005613)...

> The results suggest that mid-latitude oceanic impacts of 1 km asteroids can produce a significant, global perturbation of upper atmospheric chemistry, including multi-year global ozone depletion comparable to ozone hole records registered in the mid-1990 s.

Comment: Won't the sudden injection of a vast amount of steam into the atmosphere kick off the mother of all typhoons? Although given the remote site it might dissipate before making landfall.

Comment: @nigel222 I've never seen mention of typhoons in the literature on the subject. [Typhoons require specific conditions to form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typhoon#Genesis), just dumping water vapor into the air won't do it. Another way to look at is is there's not enough energy. [A typhoon releases 5e19 J/day](http://www.aoml.noaa.gov/hrd/tcfaq/D7.html). Our asteroid impact provided 9e20 J or about 18 days worth of energy. Most of that is not available, having been dissipated by the other effects (tsunamis, kicking water into the air, heating the surrounding ocean).

Comment: I'm not a meteorology expert, but most of the energy does end up in the air. The water is not kicked up, it is vaporised. When it condenses the energy is released to the air. Enough to run a typhoon for a couple of weeks.

Comment: @nigel222 The asteroid must push aside a column of 4e6 m^3 (900 m diameter rock diving through 1500 m) of water (causing the tsunami), and also air (causing the shock wave), then expend energy making a 13 km crater in the sea floor, then heat a roughly 1.4e9 m^3 sphere of water (heat radiating in a 1500 m sphere) 90 degrees C (about 5e17 J), and then whatever's left over reaches the surface rises as water vapor, and then that has to be in the right conditions to form a typhoon. With all that to do, there will be some odd weather, but most of it will be dissipated.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia, the impact that made the dinosaurs extinct was stronger by a factor [1000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TNT_equivalent).

> That is roughly eight billion times stronger than each of the bombs that hit Hiroshima and Nagasaki and the most energetic event on the history of Earth for hundreds of millions of years, far more powerful than any volcanic eruption, earthquake or firestorm. Such an explosion annihilated everything within a thousand miles of the impact in a split second. Such energy is equivalent to that needed to power the whole Earth for several centuries. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TNT_equivalent))

So, since your impact is considerably smaller, you won't have approximately 80% of all existing species dying out.

What you will have:

**Immediate Impact damage**

Since you land in the ocean, only some fishermen will be flattened strictly beneath the asteroid. However, the shockwave will radiate outward. Extrapolating from the Hiroshima/Nagasaki [blast damage graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_of_nuclear_explosions) (your explosion is ca. 1000000x stronger, so using the inverse-cube-law because the blast forms a sphere you should get a radius of 100x greater) you get total destruction in a radius of 100mi, moderate damage up to 200mi and light damage to 350mi.

Human life loss: if there is a large city within the destruction range, expect several tens of millions.

This does NOT account for your water landing vs. the hiroshima land blast, so the numbers might be off by quite a bit.

**Tsunami**

Since you're sticking a water landing, the displaced water will cause a tsunami. Depending on if your asteroid manages to hit a fault line and trigger earthquakes (which will result in more tsunami waves), the tsunami could easily be within the dimensions of the [2004 Indian Ocean Earthquake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2004_Indian_Ocean_earthquake_and_tsunami) or even bigger.

*Human life loss*: since humans tend to build cities along the coast, it could vary from several hundred thousand to tens of millions.

**Tectonic Damage**

If you are especially unlucky, the impact might also trigger earthquakes and volcanic eruptions all over the globe once the shockwaves of the impact get transmitted through the earth crust. Not sure about the likelihood of that, though. Probably depends on how close to a fault line your impact is and with how much strength it impacts the sea floor.

*Human life loss*: a few hundred to millions, depending on the severity

**Nuclear Winter**

Matter will be displaced by the explosion and sent up to the stratosphere where it will darken the sunlight. It will not be to the degree of the dinosaur impact, but definitely more than the [Year Without Summer 1816](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_Without_a_Summer).

Quite a few people will die from hunger, and then quite a few more will die when wars for the few existing food resources break out. Most affected: at first, the poor regions of the world; later on also the rich ones.

Next to the obvious damage to agriculture if you have several cold years in succession, it might even impede surface-to-sattelite communication. Next to satellite phones, this could affect GPS navigation and cause quite a few issues and human deaths that way. Assuming you have self-driving trucks that distribute goods, and assuming that the self-driving trucks cannot drive anymore because their navigation is gone, a large part of your infrastructure might break down and indirectly cause further deaths.

If the nuclear winter manages to create a total break-down of society, the loss of life will be a lot larger.

*Estimated human deaths*: depending on how long the nuclear winter lasts, several million to several hundreds of million

---

**Total Estimated human loss of life:**

Immediate effects: several tens to hundreds of millions

Long-term effects: several tens to thousands of millions

All in all, you will lose a measurable percentage of your earth population; it all depends on your future society / distribution of humanity, and the duration of the nuclear winter on whether you will lose 1% or 30%

Comment: Please reread the OP. Impact point is 2 km from Guam.

Comment: yeah, but who says that 400 years to the future the cities and their populations will be distributed like to day?

Comment: @subrunner In addition, the collision is the result of a terrorist attack from the colonies of the Outer Solar System as they fight a losing war against Earth, so can this force Earth to negotiate or is this too much?

Comment: Since it impacts the ocean, there's not going to be much dust kicked into the atmosphere. A lot of water vapor which has its own problems, but no nuclear winter.

Comment: @Schwern: hmmm... Not quite sure about the fault lines in the Pacific ocean, but if (and that is a big IF) the asteroid manages to trigger the 'Tectonic Damage' section, i.e. volcanic eruptions, the vulcans might cause the nuclear winter.

Comment: @subrunner [Guam is an incredibly isolated piece of land](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Guam/@13.4432039,144.7270314,4z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x671f76ff930f24ef:0x5571ae91c5b3e5a6!6m1!1e1).

Comment: Why would an asteroid impact interfere with satellite communications? Dust doesn't get in the way of radio transmissions and certainly not GPS.

Comment: @FutureHistorian If the terrorists are _threatening_ with an asteroid of that size, Earth should either capitulate immediately or pull out the kind of weaponry that can annihilate such a huge threat. Because who is to say that they are going to aim for something as isolated as Guam? If they already _have_ bombed earth that way, do they have another one ready and loaded to go? Also, when Earth is of the opinion 'We don't negotiate with terrorists', they just might pull out their own kill-all weaponry (e.g. huge laser platforms) and blow the colonists out of the sky

Comment: @Schwern Assuming you have all the dust and particles in the air that are necessary for a nuclear winter, it might effect EM waves too. I'm not a physicist, so I'm not sure how much it is effected (or if at all) but that was a thought.

Comment: @subrunner Aside from the [EMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_pulse) from the nukes themselves, no [nuclear winter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_winter) scenario I've read mentions a radio blackout.